# How can we use more than 2 cameras in one scene ? (Just like this)

Tags: camera, video, scene

[image]

Dose any one can tell how to take the scene like this in one time with more than one cameras.
When I use this

Comment: Hello :). Just to clarify: You want to render an animation with three camera views at once? What have you tried so far?

Comment: ON this gif I just combine three video with OBS Studio program . It's not build in blender So I ask for some help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a video doing what you wish on Youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vrP7H1PpTI

The video is quite old (2014) so the UI has changed but the process seems still  valid. In short, you can create copies of the scene linked to the same objects and then use compositing node to assemble all the renders into one.

There is also a Blender add-on facilitating multi-camera rendering named Render Burst. Here is the [Github repository](https://github.com/VertStretch/RenderBurst)  and [Presentation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6yXHpeidFE). It seems more adapted to picture rendering though.